Oracle - Select data from table 1 or table 2 based on some condition in table 3
I have a requirement like below:
If condition 1 satisfies from table 3
Select columns from table 1
If condition 2 satisfies from table 3
Select columns from table 2
If condition 1 and condition 2 both satisfy,
Then first check the value in table 1 ,
If the value is null then check the value in table 2

Use UNION ALL to get the rows from table1 and table2 and assign them the appropriate priority. Then you can use EXISTS to check the condition matches with table3 and the DENSE_RANK (or ROW_NUMBER) analytic function to find the highest priority rows in each group:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority) AS rnk
  FROM   (
           SELECT t1.*, 1 AS priority FROM table1 t1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT t2.*, 2 FROM table2 t2
         ) t
  WHERE  EXISTS(
           SELECT 1
           FROM   Table3 t3
           WHERE  t.id = t3.id
         )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;


Alternatively, use FULL OUTER JOIN and COALESCE/NVL2:
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
       NVL2(t1.id, t1.value1, t2.value1) AS value1,
       NVL2(t1.id, t1.value2, t2.value2) AS value2
FROM   Table1 t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table3 t3
         WHERE  t1.id = t3.id OR t2.id = t3.id
       )

